# When will SSDT-BI be available for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql, visual-studio-2015, ssis

From Microsoft's download page, SSDT-BI (SQL Server Data Tools Business Intelligence) for Visual Studio 2013 is available but not for 2015.  When will Microsoft release SSDT-BI for VS 2015?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

Comment: Available as of June, 2016. [MSDN: SSDT-BI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's all part of one installer as of [the August update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ssdt/sql-server-data-tools-preview-update-for-august-2015)

> The SSDT Preview update for August 2015 includes a new unified setup for both Database and Business Intelligence (BI) tools in Visual Studio 2015.

As commented by Adam Dunn, the [October preview has added SSRS and SSAS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ssdt/sql-server-data-tools-preview-update-for-october-2015).

Comment: As of the September preview, only Integration Service projects where available in Visual Studio 2015. Reporting Services and Analysis Services are still to come

Comment: The October preview has now added Report and Analysis Services. The Reports can be created with compatibility going back to SSRS 2008. You can read the [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2015/10/27/sql-server-data-tools-preview-update-for-october-2015.aspx) or [download](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)